# ECS changes owner in folder

Tags: docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have a Dockerfile whose last lines are:

```
RUN mkdir /usr/local/workdir/my-folder
RUN chown -R my-user: /usr/local/workdir/my-folder
USER my-user
WORKDIR /usr/local/workdir/
```

When I run `ls -lhat` (locally) inside my docker I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 my-user my-user 4.0K Sep 23 11:49 my-folder
```

I push this docker to aws ECR, and then I run a job from ECS, and that job includes an `ls -lhat` too. However, this time I get

```
drwxr-xr-x 10 root root 4.0K Sep 23 11:49 my-folder
```

So ECS has changed the owner of `my-folder`. Why does this happen? Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: How are you launching the container?  In particular, is any sort of volume mount on to `my-folder` involved?

Comment: yeah, there's indeed a volume mount in `my-folder`

Comment: The owner of the mounted folder (`ls -ld .` when you're in the directory) will take precedence over what you set in the Dockerfile.

Comment: ok, so: Is there a way to avoid this overriding, or keeping `my-user` as the owner, without having to avoid the mount?

Comment: would a read-only mount work?